# How to create groups and count variables to find relationships between variables?

Tags: r, group-by, rstudio, relationship, plyr

I'm having problems summarizing count and aggregate functions with conditions on the fields.

Example:

```
df = tbl_df(data.frame(
    users=c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4"), 
    projects=c("100", "101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110", "111", "112"), 
    from=c("0", "0", "111", "106", "111", "101", "0", "101", "0", "100", "106", "108", "0")))
```

The table contains users (users), user-owned projects (projects), and projects that originate from other projects from other users (from).

I'd like to know who are the users who have more relationships with other users through the use of projects. As the table shows, the projects of a user can be used by other users (from) and the user can have their own projects (projects).

I thought about counting the relationships: amount of user projects used by other users and number of user projects that he is not the owner of.

Could anyone give me a hint how to do this using ddply or another function like summarize or group_by?

I was able to generate a function using for, but I know this is not the most appropriate solution, especially when I have millions of users in processing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
out <- data.frame(summarize(group_by(df, users),
                     number_of_user_owned_projects = length(df$from[df$from %in% projects]),
                     number_of_projects_from_others = length(unique(from[from != 0]))))
out
  users number_of_user_owned_projects number_of_projects_from_others
1     1                             3                              2
2     2                             2                              2
3     3                             1                              1
4     4                             2                              3
```

Comment: In number_of_user_owned_projects, I would like to identify the number of projects in the **projects** column that are in the **from** column. Not just the amount of the projects. For example, user 1 has project 101 being used twice by different users. So, I would like to have this analysis for each user project and the total per user.

Comment: @AidanGawronski how does `length(df$from[df$from %in% projects])` work?

Comment: @phil_t When you you use the full reference (df$from) it ignores the group_by

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = df %>% group_by(from) %>% summarise(cntr = n()) %>% filter(from != 0)

#temp

#    from  cntr
#1    100     1
#2    101     2
#3    106     2
#4    108     1
#5    111     2


output = left_join(df, temp, by = c("projects" = "from")) %>% 
             group_by(users) %>% 
             summarize(user_owned = sum(cntr, na.rm = TRUE), other_owned = sum(from != 0))

#output

#   users user_owned other_owned

#1      1          3           2
#2      2          2           2
#3      3          1           1
#4      4          2           3
```

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your help.